# Question related to uniform convergence of continuous functions

Tags: real-analysis

Given $f : [0, 1] \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$, let $f_n : [0, 1] \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be a sequence of continuous functions satisfying $|f_n (x) - f(x)| < \frac{1}{n}$ for $x \in [0, 1]$. For each $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $f_n$ satisfies the following estimate: for all $x, x' \in [0, 1]$ we have $|f_n (x) - f_n (x')| \leq n|x - x'|$. Prove that for all $x, x' \in [0, 1]$ we have $|f(x) - f(x')| \leq 1000 |x - x'| ^ \frac{1}{2}$.

I know $f$ is continuous, but the condition needed seems to be stronger.

Comment: Just to put some terminology to your situation here, your function $f$ is called Hölder continuous https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder_condition

Comment: Are you looking to add more conditions?

Comment: I'm looking to prove a stronger form of continuity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably a tighter constant than the one stated can be achieved in the final inequality.

First we will use the triangle inequality to deduce
$$
|f(x) - f(x')| \leq |f(x)-f_n(x)| + |f_n(x)-f_n(x')| + |f_n(x')-f(x')|.
$$
By assumption, we then have
$$
|f(x) - f(x')| \leq \frac{2}{n} + n|x-x'| \quad \forall n \in \mathbb{N}.
$$

Now comes the somehow tricky part. Our goal is to find a bound on the right hand side of the last estimate independent of $n$. Given any pair $(x,x')$ we can always find $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that
$$
|x-x'| \in \left(\frac{2}{(n+1)^2};\frac{2}{n^2}\right].
$$
Recalling $(n+1)/n \leq 2$ for any positive $n$, we deduce
$$
|f(x) - f(x')| \leq \frac{2}{n} + n \frac{2}{n^2} = \frac{4}{n} = 2\sqrt{2} \frac{(n+1)}{n} \, \sqrt{\frac{2}{(n+1)^2}} < 4\sqrt{2}|x-x'|^{1/2}
$$
as claimed.